# why do i have an elasticsearch modulenotfounderror even if it's running?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, request

i am using elastic search to do searching on a bunch of json documents, and for adding these json documents i am using python elasticsearch. but when i try to run the code i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "search/elasticsearch/crud02.py", line 4, in <module>
    from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'elasticsearch'
```

and here is my code:

```
import json 
import os, sys

from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch 
es = Elasticsearch([{'host':'localhost', 'port': 9200}])

data=open(item, encoding = 'utf-8').read()

es.index(index='textes_juridiques', doc_type='_doc', id=1,body=json.loads(r.content))

res = es.get(index='textes_juridiques', id=1) print(res)
```

please help me find the solution because even thought elasticsearch is installed (last version) and running and when i do :

```
 res = requests.get('http://localhost:9200')
```

i get the right response. 
thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error says that your environment does not have the Python Elasticsearch Client library installed.

Please check the [documentation](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/). You can install it by running the command:

```
pip install elasticsearch
```

If you have already installed, please make sure you are running your script in the proper environment (conda, virtualenv, etc).

Hope this is helpful :)